# Multiple health check curls in docker health check

Tags: docker, health-check

In order to ensure the health check of my container, I need to perform test calls to multiple URLS.

`curl -f http://example.com` and `curl -f http://example2.com`

Is it possible to perform multiple curl calls for a docker health check?

Answer (score 5):

You can set a script as the healthcheck command that contains a more complex logic to perform the healthcheck. That way you can do multiple requests via curl and let the script only return positive if all requests succeeded.

```dockerfile
# example dockerfile
COPY files/healthcheck.sh /healthcheck.sh
RUN chmod +x /healthcheck.sh
HEALTHCHECK --interval=60s --timeout=10s --start-period=10s \  
    CMD /healthcheck.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I cannot test, I think you can use the following

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD (curl --fail http://example.com && curl --fail http://example2.com) || exit 1
```

If you want first to check this command manually (without exit part), you can check the last error code by

```
echo $? -> in linux
```

and

```
echo %errorlevel% -> in windows
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it only calls the first URL.